# Can you identify these LEGO bags from the thrift store? Mostly white and dark grey pieces, and some bared doors

Tags: set-identification

I got these at the thrift store. What set did these come from?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Based on:

[BRICK 1X16, Ø4,9](https://brickset.com/parts/design-3703) in white

[LATTICE FOR FRAME 4X6](https://brickset.com/parts/design-92589) in Medium Stone Grey

[TRAPDOOR FRAME 6X8](https://brickset.com/parts/design-92107) in Dark Stone Grey

[4504228: Wall Element 1X6X5, Abs](https://brickset.com/parts/4504228/wall-element-1x6x5-abs)  in white

and the trans blue parts window pieces

These bags are from:

[60047-1: Police Station](https://brickset.com/sets/60047-1/Police-Station)

[image]

Comment: Nice hunt!  I was here, but got stuck on that long blue pin in bag 6.  Bricklink doesn't have it listed at all in it's inventory.

Comment: Both Brickset and Bricklink actually list 1 piece of 3L Technic pin.